# PHP: Get the position (x, y) of the layer of PSD file

Tags: php, imagemagick, psd

I am using Imagemagick with PHP and want to get the position of the layer (x,y) but dont know how.

I read the PSD file in PHP and read every layer in it like this:

```
for ($i = 0, $num_layers = $im->getNumberImages(); $i < $num_layers; ++$i) { ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

for ($i = 0, $num_layers = $im->getNumberImages(); $i < $num_layers; ++$i) {
    $im->setImageIndex($i);         //this
    $im->setIteratorIndex($i);      //or this is kinda redundant
    $pagedata=$im->getImagePage();

    print("x,y: " . $pagedata["x"].", ".$pagedata["y"]."<br />\n");
    print("w,h: " . $pagedata["width"].", ".$pagedata["height"]."<br />\n");

    //export layer
    //$im->writeImage('layer_' . $i . '.png');
}

?>
```

Comment: For even more metadata use
foreach($im->getImageProperties("*") as $k => $v) print("$k: $v<br/>\n");

Comment: i already use getImageProperties but how to fetch also the comment of the psd file if you set one in the graphics program?

Comment: I'm sorry, you can't with ImageMagick AFAIK. You also can't extract slices, guides, text layers .. well .. basically nothing but rasterized layers WITH pixels (empty layers doesn't show up) ..

Comment: or just plain php and reading some header of the bytecode from the image directly?

Comment: You could try that. There's a PSDReader class on PHPClasses ([link](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17603.html)). But I've looked over the source, but can't find any functionality which extracts the comment.

Comment: I already saw that very old php class, but use my own using imagemagick.

Comment: Hi guys, anyone knows how to get the layers name using php? if that is possible then please help me out, any link reference or anything solution will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: not 100% sure, but try `$im->getImageProperty('label')`. (You probably need to set the correct layer first through `setIteratorIndex`) @HimanshuUpadhyay