# How can I read psd file using php

Tags: php, psd

I need to read `PSD` file into `PHP` code and get group layers and X-Y positions.

How can i do it? I've heard of ImageMagick but never worked on it.

If you guys have some links to get started please provide it to me.

Comment: Not sure if this helps: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3627-PHP-Open-images-in-the-PhotoShop-PSD-format.html

Comment: @karmafunk many thanks for response but that was the first thing i have tried but its converting into image but i want to read payers..

Comment: In case nothing exists, you can do it yourself by parsing the file: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/

Answer (score 7):

You *can* use [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) for this, using something like:

```
$im = new Imagick("image.psd");

foreach($im as $layer) {
  // do something with each $layer

  // example: save all layers to separate PNG files
  $layer->writeImage("layer" . ++$i . ".png");
}
```

Also, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6804559) to a question similar to yours, and has some code examples for how to get `x,y` positions of layers, for instance.