# How to display psd file using php?

Tags: php

I was trying to read a psd file from database as like pdf or images but I failed.
Is there any way to read or display psd file in browser?

Comment: i beleive not, becose is not an open source, so need to known how is byte done

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) for this,

```
$im = new Imagick("image.psd");

foreach($im as $layer) {
  // do something with each $layer

  // example: save all layers to separate PNG files
  $layer->writeImage("layer" . ++$i . ".png");
}
```

Refer to this question too:  [PHP: Get the position (x, y) of the layer of PSD file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801095/php-get-the-position-x-y-of-the-layer-of-psd-file/6804559#6804559)

OR You could use something like this:
[PSD Library - Read .psd files without any 3rd party libraries.](https://github.com/hasokeric/php-psd)

Comment: thanks @Bilal . i know this process. It is just converter psd to png. i said i want to display accurate psd file in my output.

Comment: A PSD file is a file format used by and specific for Adobe Photoshop. Other applications (like your webbrowser) do not know how to read it. You need to convert it to another format.

Comment: yes bro .  thanks for your suggest. can i make a download link of this psd file from database? @Bilal

Comment: do you want the user to download the image directly from the db itself?

Comment: yes user can be download but not image psd file.that mean i want to make a link for psd file to download it.

Comment: Refer to this SO questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329586/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-php-and-mysql-db

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below. It uses a webapi but it's free and has no limitations.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://server.com/image.psd';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.rest7.com/v1/image_convert.php?url=' . $url . '&format=png'));

if (@$data->success !== 1)
{
    die('Failed');
}
$image = file_get_contents($data->file);
file_put_contents('rendered_page.png', $image);
```

Additional bonus- it reads not only PSD images but many, many more.

You can get more examples here: 
http://rest7.com/image_convert

I am not affiliated with this website but I use it for over a week now so if you have questions I can try to answer :)